# How to fix "Tensor object is not callable" error in keras code?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I am making a multi layer auto-encoder using Keras and I am getting the error where I make the Model of decoder.

I saw a matching problem in Stackoverflow but my code isn't incorrect and is complete, so not missing anything

```
encoding_dim=16


i=Input(shape=(122,))




encoded=Dense(64,activation='relu')(i)

encoded1=Dense(32,activation='relu')(encoded)

encoded2=Dense(16,activation='relu')(encoded1)


decoded=Dense(32,activation='relu')(encoded2)

decoded2 =Dense(64,activation='relu')(decoded)

decoded3 =Dense(122,activation='relu')(decoded2)

autoencoder = Model(i, decoded3)


ec = Model(i,encoded)

encoded_input=Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))

decoder_layer=autoencoder.layers[-3](encoded_input)
decoder_layer=autoencoder.layers[-2](decoder_layer)
decoder_layer=autoencoder.layers[-1](decoder_layer)


**decoder=Model(encoded_input,decoder_layer(encoded_input))**
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```py
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

decoder_layer                 # <-- is a LAYER
decoder_layer(encoded_input)  # <-- is a TENSOR
```

`Model` expects `inputs=` and `outputs=` to be both *layers*, not *tensors*; a layer fed an input evalutes to a tensor. Fix:

```py
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer)
```